# How to setup elastic cluster for huge amount of data?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, bigdata

I am asked to setup elastic search cluster for about 100 TB of text Data!
I already know how to do searches and aggs in elastic, but I really don't know how to setup cluster with more than one node for such big data!
I mean how many masters, zoe keepers, CDs, ... ? or Do I need to have one dedicate server for activeMQ? ...

Is there any document for explaining that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES is a distributed system and creating a cluster with 1 node or 1000 node doesn't make much difference.

What you can do in your case, is to have some master node and more data nodes to create a big cluster.

> The master node is responsible for lightweight cluster-wide actions
>   such as creating or deleting an index, tracking which nodes are part
>   of the cluster, and deciding which shards to allocate to which nodes.
>
> Data nodes hold the shards that contain the documents you have
>   indexed. Data nodes handle data related operations like CRUD, search,
>   and aggregations. These operations are I/O-, memory-, and
>   CPU-intensive. It is important to monitor these resources and to add
>   more data nodes if they are overloaded.

You can choose master nodes of small size(if they don't hold data) and data nodes are of large size.

Below is the configuration for master node.

```
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
cluster.name: elasticsearch_hobbes ## note this cluster name must be same for all the es nodes in the same cluster
node.name: "elasticsearch_001_master"// give 002 for other master node
node.master: true
**node.data: false (This master node will not hold the data)**
path.data: /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/
path.logs: /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

And below is the config for data node.

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch_hobbes
node.name: "node2"
node.master: false
node.data : true
http.port: 9201
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
```

You can then go to `KOPF plugin` of your master node, by clicking the http://localhost:9200/_plugin/kopf/#!/cluster And see the below screen, which shows all the three nodes in the cluster.

Note:- Please follow https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf to install KOPF plugin. And let me know if you face any problem setting up the cluster.

Comment: Just note that the site plugins such as Kopf cannot be installed anymore as of ES 5. You should consider using Kibana or Cerebro instead: https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro

Comment: some one said me I should have dedicated servers for activeMQ, Content Dispather, ...?? Do I really need them? How much data can I import to ES in one second? Is there any soft limit?

Comment: @kamal, its a best practice to queue the data and update them in batch, activeMQ or DB queue can be used for it. How much data you can import to ES in one second depends on the various factor(hardware, document size, network etc).

Comment: As I understood, in ES, there are two different nodes, Master and Data. Am I right? Is there any other node needed?

Comment: @kamal , please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html for different types of nodes ES support and use them according to your use-case.